# How to convert Minutes to Hours Minutes and Seconds in SQL?

Tags: sql, date, datetime, oracle11g

Currently I am using this query, which gives me duration in minutes.

**Part of My query**

```
Select 
   E.xyme

From
    (SELECT Timee as xyme from  
            (select round(avg(tableT.DURATIONMIN),2) as Timee
                FROM ownerName.tableT tableT
                   where tableT.FLAG = 0 )
    )E
```

Output would be

```
Xyme
----
125.58
```

**Output Looking for**

```
Xyme
----
2 hours, 5 minutes, 35 seconds
```

**Part solution**
I know we can use something like below but I am not able to implement.

```
 floor((sysdate-Timee)*24)
  || ' HOURS ' ||
  mod(floor((sysdate-Timee)*24*60),60)
  || ' MINUTES ' ||
  mod(floor((sysdate-Timee)*24*60*60),60)
  || ' SECS ' Duration
```

Comment: When you say you are not able to implent, is there any particular reason?\

Comment: Hi, what I meant what I am doing something incorrect, it is not giving me result(output).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert the numeric value for the minutes to an interval type using the [`numtodsinterval()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions117.htm), and then [`extract()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions059.htm) the elements from that:

```
select extract (hour from numtodsinterval(timee, 'MINUTE')) || ' hours, '
  || extract (minute from numtodsinterval(timee, 'MINUTE')) || ' minutes, '
  || extract (second from numtodsinterval(timee, 'MINUTE')) || ' seconds' as xyme
from (select 125.58 as timee from dual);

XYME                                   
----------------------------------------
2 hours, 5 minutes, 34.8 seconds
```

You can `round` or `trunc` the seconds value as appropriate; looks like you want `round` from your sample.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need first take average in subquery then do the extract in outer query. so do you think I should still use `avg(tableT.DUURATIONMIN) as Timee` ?

Comment: heh @AlexPoole u ware quick :) but the same solution that I wanted to provide :)

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked but it is giving me big decimal number, I used only `avg(tableT.DURATIONMIN) as Timee`.

Comment: @Mowgli - just replace my `select ... from dual` subquery with your own. How you're displaying the result doesn't affect what the data means or how you're getting that number in the first place. The `round` in the subquery might give a slightly wrong answer though, I'd skip that and just round the final seconds value?